# Python login program,with bcrypt

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, passwords, salt

I'm writing a python script (in python3.4),it hashes the passwords,and another script logs the user in.

The one that hashes the password:

```
import bcrypt
password1 = input("pass: ")
password=b"password1"
salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)

f=open("passwd.txt","w")
print(hashed,file=f)
f.close()

f1=open("salty.txt","w")
print(salt,file=f1)
f1.close()



if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed:
   print("It Matches")
else:
    print("It Does not Match")
```

The other:

```
import bcrypt
password1 = input("pass: ")
password=b"password1"
f=open("passwd.txt","r")
for i in f:
    hashed1=i
f.close()

hashed=b"hashed1"

f1=open("salty.txt","r")
for j in f1:
    salt=j
f1.close()

if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed:
    print("It Matches")
else:
    print("It Does not Match)
```

if i try to use the second to enter the password and compare it tho the other it tells me this:

```
ValueError: Invalid salt
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the second case you are passing the `hashpw` function the string literal `hashed1`. This is incorrect usage. As far as I understand it, you should be passing the function the users hashed password, as bcrypt will attach the salt as part of the hash.

It looks like you may be trying to convert the hash from a unicode string to a bytestring incorrectly. I see you have `hashed=b"hashed1"`, which is assigning a literal bytestring to the variable `hashed` try `hashed = bytes(hashed1)` instead.

Comment: So how would you do the soxnd part?

Comment: See in my answer, I'm pretty sure you are incorrectly trying to convert Unicode to bytestring